# Win32 segmented, double buffered console

Tags: winapi, console

Why do I even bother with this? Well, it's a pretty handy debug tool for large programs.

The concept is the following: I would like to split the console area into two parts:
 - the upper part double buffered (I already know how to do this)
 - the lower part functioning as a regular standard output (as in: scrolls, responds to scroll control, etc.)

An example image:

[image: dbuffed console]

What I would like to achieve is to keep the persistent part always on top, while the scrollable part indeed scrolls, and responds to the scroll control on the right.

I have some knowledge of the required functions (*CreateConsoleScreenBuffer*, *SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer*, *SetConsoleCursorPosition*, etc.), but I'm struggling with the implementation.

I know it is possible, because I saw it in other programs. Therefore I would like to ask for suggestions on how to do this right.

Comment: This isn't really a good fit for this site. We're about specific questions rather than a call for general suggestions and tips.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write code to do this. You know the APIs to use. Scrolling is something you will have to implement yourself. Tedious, yet pretty straight forward to do.

Comment: you don't say...but it is my fault that I always forget not to post questions here.